# rails upload csv with FasterCSV to database IN UTF8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, utf-8, upload, fastercsv

rails - 2.3.8

ruby  - 1.8.7

I really searched old questions but found nothing.

The deal is: Read from a .csv and update that info to my table in UTF8, but special chars like 'á','è','û' are changed for '?'.

My table supports all this kind of chars. here is the code i tryed:

```
FasterCSV.open("public/files/some.csv", :encoding => "U") do |csv|
    csv.each do |line|
        Model.update_all("column1 = '#{line}'", "id= 129476")
    end 
end
```

so line have this`Ácido acetilsalicílico;Ácido acetilsalicílico;Não Comercializado`

on my terminal using debugger before the update to check, line have this:

```
�cido acetilsalic�lico;�cido acetilsalic�lico;N�o Comercializado
```

and on the table the content saved is: 
?cido acetilsalic?lico;?cido acetilsalic?lico;N?o Comercializado

I did another test which consisted in read the file (line by line) and write a new file with each line read, before each write I checked the line on my terminal and it shown `�cido acetilsalic�lico;�cido acetilsalic�lico;N�o Comercializado`.
But after all the file was written,when i opened that new file, surprise all the chars were well displayed how!!

I need help to understand why write in the database the chars are all stupid!!! xD

Comment: Can you confirm that your database encoding is set to utf-8? What if you manually connect to DB and run an update statement outside of Rails --- does it store in UTF-8 or ASCII?

Comment: Yap it recognize UTF-8.
Update table set column1 = "àèéáÂÛ  £€ô" where id = 1 |||

Or do i need to test an update from a remote terminal?!